# Nesting List within a List and Numpy Arrays

Tags: python, concatenation, cell-array

How to insert some of the matrices (like images) in each cell of a list or array and then use each of matrices as an array (like cell arrays in Matlab)?
I have tried doing it, as in the following code:

```
    a = []
    for dcmfile in dcmfiles:
        dcm_image = pydicom.dcmread(os.path.join(root, dcmfile))
        a.append([dcm_image.pixel_array])
        volume_image = np.concatenate((a, ?), 1)  # problem is in this line because two variables are needed to the "concatenate".
```

َAlso, I have checked the below code but it has been had an error:

```
    volume_image = {}
    for i, dcmfile in dcmfiles:
        dcm_image = pydicom.dcmread(os.path.join(root, dcmfile))
        volume_image[i] = dcm_image.pixel_array
```

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says that at some point, python expects 2 objects (values) but only one is sent. The culprit is in:

```
for i, dcmfile in dcmfiles:
```

Here you are iterating through the elements of `dcmfile`, therefore the `for .. in` statement will return one element at time to operate with. However, you are aasking for two elements, namely `i` and `dcmfile`, hence the error.

You should change it with:

```
for i, dcmfile in enumerate(dcmfiles):
```

if `dcmfiles` is an iterable or in:

```
for i, dcmfile in dcmfiles.iteritems(): # for python 2.x
for i, dcmfile in dcmfiles.items(): # for python 3.x
```

if `dcmfiles` is a dictionary